# ASP.NET Is it possible to call methods within Server Tag using Eval()?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an aspx page which contains a repeater. I can output data using Eval() but I want to know if it is possible to call a method that belongs to another class and pass it the value of Eval()?

For example, in the `<ItemTemplate>` section of the repeater:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
       <td>
          <%# ClassName.Method( Eval("value1") ) %>
       </td>
       <td>
          <%#  Eval("value2") %>
       </td>
    </tr>                  
 </ItemTemplate>
```

If it is possible to do this, what is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, but you need to provide the full name and to cast the result of the Eval function, which returns System.Object instances.

```
<%# Namespace.ClassName.Method( (string)Eval("value1") ) %>
```

Here, method is public static, but you can use instance methods also.

```
<%# new Namespace.ClassName((string)Eval("value1")).Method2((int)Eval("value2")) %>
```